# Array of url/links is not printing all the urls in it

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I have an object obtained from postman REST API calls, I am looping through the object to obtain certain data's(name, description, url). When I loop through I store them in an array. When I log the data on this line "console.log(response.results[key].data.properties.url)" I get the urls which is fine. but after adding them to the array and I print the array only 2 of the urls get returned. This is my code you can run it on JSnippet.

```
    let response = {"results": [
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Learn how to perform Browse View Actions in Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to filter, sort, favorite, open, and add items.",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Learn how to perform Browse View Actions in Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to filter, sort, favorite, open, and add items."
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69107433,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-22T13:06:20",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "How to perform Browse View actions in Smart View",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "How to perform Browse View actions in Smart View"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "https://youtu.be/uGgLHbUykV4",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "How to perform Browse View actions in Smart View",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "How to perform Browse View actions in Smart View"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Instruction video to install AppWorks Gateway",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Instruction video to install AppWorks Gateway"
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69107282,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "Installing AppWorks Gateway",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Installing AppWorks Gateway"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "http://stage.ss.vidavee.com/vidad/sunnyside.vidavee.com/opentext/OTDocs/7486A99E41109E4141BCFB8078D036C8.mp4",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "Installing AppWorks Gateway",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "Installing AppWorks Gateway"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T15:11:01",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Marketing Video",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Marketing Video"
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69107422,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-20T15:11:01",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "Buy OpenText",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Buy OpenText"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "http://sunnyside.vidavee.com/opentext/doc/D2A8F0A6D155FE5D7CD4882FF2B5EE4A?AF_deliveryChannel=responsive&p3=on",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "Buy OpenText",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "Buy OpenText"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Learn how to perform Document Actions in Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to reserve, download, add a new version, unreserve, and edit documents.",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Learn how to perform Document Actions in Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to reserve, download, add a new version, unreserve, and edit documents."
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69106725,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-22T13:07:43",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "How to perform Document Actions in Smart View",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "How to perform Document Actions in Smart View"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "https://youtu.be/GM36EiuBPp8",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "How to perform Document Actions in Smart View",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "How to perform Document Actions in Smart View"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Learn how to access the basic Content Actions in Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to use the Inline Action Bar, Action Bar, and Properties page to access basic Content Actions such as sharing, copying, and moving.",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Learn how to access the basic Content Actions in Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to use the Inline Action Bar, Action Bar, and Properties page to access basic Content Actions such as sharing, copying, and moving."
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69106503,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-22T13:05:04",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "How to access Content Actions in Smart View",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "How to access Content Actions in Smart View"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "https://youtu.be/9htthQfRL1g",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "How to access Content Actions in Smart View",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "How to access Content Actions in Smart View"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Learn what you can do with your profile in OpenText Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to update your profile; add, edit, or delete comments in the activity feed; and customize your notification and security settings.",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Learn what you can do with your profile in OpenText Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to update your profile; add, edit, or delete comments in the activity feed; and customize your notification and security settings."
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69107289,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-22T13:15:04",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "Work with your profile in Smart View",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Work with your profile in Smart View"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "https://youtu.be/j-aOeCpRvEs",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "Work with your profile in Smart View",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "Work with your profile in Smart View"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac pretium arcu, fringilla convallis nisl. Nullam id sem accumsan, lacinia turpis eget, volutpat tellus. Curabitur nibh velit, vestibulum quis blandit sed, viverra in lorem. Cras metus orci, tempor ut viverra eu, commodo quis velit.",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac pretium arcu, fringilla convallis nisl. Nullam id sem accumsan, lacinia turpis eget, volutpat tellus. Curabitur nibh velit, vestibulum quis blandit sed, viverra in lorem. Cras metus orci, tempor ut viverra eu, commodo quis velit."
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69106511,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-22T13:57:21",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "Installing Enterprise Connect",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Installing Enterprise Connect"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "http://stage.ss.vidavee.com/vidad/sunnyside.vidavee.com/opentext/OTDocs/7486A99E41109E4141BCFB8078D036C8.mp4",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "Installing Enterprise Connect",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "Installing Enterprise Connect"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Learn how to perform the basic Content Actions in Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to view metadata, rename, share, move, copy, and delete an item.",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Learn how to perform the basic Content Actions in Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to view metadata, rename, share, move, copy, and delete an item."
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69106659,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-22T13:04:13",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "How to perform Content Actions in Smart View",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "How to perform Content Actions in Smart View"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "https://youtu.be/WhTlt9w2OR4",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "How to perform Content Actions in Smart View",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "How to perform Content Actions in Smart View"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Learn what you can do with your profile in OpenText Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to update your profile; add, edit, or delete comments in the activity feed; and customize your notification and security settings.",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Learn what you can do with your profile in OpenText Content Server Smart View 16.2.4. This video will show you how to update your profile; add, edit, or delete comments in the activity feed; and customize your notification and security settings."
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69107434,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-22T13:16:33",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "Work with other users’ profiles in Smart View",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Work with other users’ profiles in Smart View"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "https://youtu.be/kzEIoZG80gU",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "Work with other users’ profiles in Smart View",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "Work with other users’ profiles in Smart View"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "properties": {
                "container": false,
                "container_size": 0,
                "create_date": "2018-11-20T09:56:05",
                "create_user_id": 2582434,
                "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac pretium arcu, fringilla convallis nisl. Nullam id sem accumsan, lacinia turpis eget, volutpat tellus. Curabitur nibh velit, vestibulum quis blandit sed, viverra in lorem. Cras metus orci, tempor ut viverra eu, commodo quis velit.",
                "description_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam ac pretium arcu, fringilla convallis nisl. Nullam id sem accumsan, lacinia turpis eget, volutpat tellus. Curabitur nibh velit, vestibulum quis blandit sed, viverra in lorem. Cras metus orci, tempor ut viverra eu, commodo quis velit."
                },
                "external_create_date": null,
                "external_identity": "",
                "external_identity_type": "",
                "external_modify_date": null,
                "external_source": "",
                "favorite": false,
                "id": 69106512,
                "mime_type": null,
                "modify_date": "2018-11-22T13:59:16",
                "modify_user_id": 2582434,
                "name": "Installing Records Management",
                "name_multilingual": {
                    "en": "Installing Records Management"
                },
                "owner_group_id": 751247,
                "owner_user_id": 2582434,
                "parent_id": 69106987,
                "reserved": false,
                "reserved_date": null,
                "reserved_user_id": 0,
                "short_summary": "",
                "size": null,
                "size_formatted": "",
                "summary": "",
                "type": 140,
                "type_name": "URL",
                "url": "http://stage.ss.vidavee.com/vidad/sunnyside.vidavee.com/opentext/OTDocs/7486A99E41109E4141BCFB8078D036C8.mp4",
                "versions_control_advanced": false,
                "volume_id": -2001
            },
            "regions": {
                "OTName": "Installing Records Management",
                "OTName_expand": {
                    "value_index": 0,
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "attribute_map": {
                                "lang": "en"
                            },
                            "value": "Installing Records Management"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
]};

    var nameoOfLink = [];
    descriptionOfVideo = [];
    var urlOfVideo = [];

    for(let key in response.results){
      console.log(response.results[key].data.properties.url);
      if(response.results[key].data.properties !== null){
        nameoOfLink[nameoOfLink.length] = 
        response.results[key].data.properties.name;
       descriptionOfVideo[descriptionOfVideo.length] = 
       response.results[key].data.properties.description;
       urlOfVideo[urlOfVideo.length] = 
       response.results[key].data.properties.url;
      }
    }

    console.log(urlOfVideo.toString());
```

Comment: When I log the array out on the last line, it's only printing the first two links but my log in this line shows all of it, every other array prints out all the data fine

Comment: Small recommendation... instead of referencing the current array length for adding new items, I would recommend using the .push() method instead on the array.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp

Comment: @TimHunter I tried push first, it only returns the first two elements still for the url array

Comment: Yeah, using .push() isn't a solution for your question. Just a best practice recommendation. For your issue, it may be that it's not parsing the JSON correctly so the URLs aren't getting referenced. Is there any distinguishable difference in the URL format for the ones that work correctly vs the ones that don't?

Comment: @TimHunter The only thing i notice is that the second URL ends with a ".mp4", so after that second url nothing gets printed out

Comment: When you do an console log of the array length, does it show there being more elements in the array or is the length only 2?

Comment: @TimHunter, Yes it shows there are 10 elements in it, and also if i log out element at each index "urlOfVideo[3]", I get the url. I am starting to think its the online code editor I am using

Comment: Mkay, I recommend using a loop to run through the array and print them instead of relying on the .toString() for it. I cannot say I know the exact root of the issue for why console logging is being weird in your case.

Comment: @TimHunter Thanks the looping through the array works, so its means the links are in there. I guess its the toString()

Comment: No prob mate, happy to help as well as I can.